# how to make js wait for the result and treatment of fetch request to continuous on?

Tags: javascript

I'm still a js beginner and full of doubts. You guys from stack overflow are helping a lot. Thanks!

**Context:** I want to make a fetch request to my API after the user logs in, and verifies if the user is admin or costumer, so then it continues on. To do so, I need to make another request to the user's endpoint to verify it.

The problem is that javascript doesn't wait for the return of the userRole() function to treat it and then print 'ok' to the console. It prints first!

I've tried a lot of solutions but couldn't make it work.

```
let userRole = async (id, token) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      `https://lu-teperino-arq-developer.herokuapp.com/usuarios/${id}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + token
        }
      }
    );
    let data = await response.json();

    if (data.profissional === true) return "admin";
    else if (data.profissional === false) return "customer";
    else return "";
  };

  const userId = "";
  const token = "";

  userRole(userId, token).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  console.log("ok");
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is working as it supposed to because JS is asynchronous in nature. Whatever you want to do after the userRole finishes all that code must be inside the then callback

Comment: You need to also await `userRole()`. Of course you need to call `userRole` inside a function marked as `async` if you want to await it. If you don't want to do that you can also do `userRole().then().then(console.log)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close. Currently, only your `console.log(data)` is waiting for your asynchronous function to finish. You've defined an `async` function but didn't *really* `await` it anywhere. It's not enough to simply define a function as `async` to be able to put `await` inside of it. That function now must be either `await`ed or `.then()`ed itself.

Think about it: any steps that depend on `userRole` completing *are also awaiting*. **You cannot have** ***synchronous*** **code depending/waiting on** ***asynchronous*** **code.** You're going to have to have the entirety of the process that is waiting for `userRole` be asynchronous.

---

If **all** of your code is waiting on `userRole`, you could perhaps make `window.onload` `async`? I'm not in a work-space where I can test right now, but perhaps try this instead:

```js
window.onload = async () => {
  const userRole = async (id, token) => {
    // current code...
  }

  const data = await userRole('id-123', 'token-abc');

  console.log(data);
  console.log('ok');

  // Now do the rest of your stuff
}
```

If this isn't the case, then your solution is to just remember that everything after running `userRole` that's waiting on it **is also asynchronous**. You'll just have to put the rest of the dependant code in your `.then()` (or put it all in another `async` function and use `await`s, like I did above, just not with `window.onload`):

```js
const userRole = async (id, token) => {
  // current code...
}

userRole('id-123', 'token-abc').then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  console.log('ok'); // <-- do it here

  // The rest of the code that needs userRole's response
});
```

Comment: Got it! All must be synchronous or asynchronous, but not both. I'll stay with second solution, looks better to my needs now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GabrielM.Linassi Yep, you’ve got it now! Asynchronous code is very powerful but it’s definitely got a steep learning curve. Thankfully `async` and `await` make it much easier. Using 100% Promise syntax gets messy fast.

Comment: Thanks @matthew-e-brown! Your answer was very clarifying. Now I have a better understanding on how to work with async/await.

Answer (score 1):

You should use it by this way:

```
let checkRole = async (req, res, next) => {
  let userRole = async (id, token) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      `https://lu-teperino-arq-developer.herokuapp.com/usuarios/${id}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + token
        }
      }
    );
    let data = await response.json();

    if (data.profissional === true) return "admin";
    else if (data.profissional === false) return "customer";
    else return "";
  };

  const userId = "";
  const token = "";

  let role = await userRole(userId, token).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  console.log("ok");
};
```